# If $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$ and $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, prove $12|abc$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I know from $a^2+b^2=c^2$ that $a = st$, b = $\frac{s^2-t^2}{2}$, c = $\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}$ , where $s>t>1$, where $s$ and $t$ are both odd, but how do I make use of this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$s,t$ odd means $s^2\equiv t^2\equiv 1\mod 8$, hence $b$ is divisible by $4$. If neither $s$ nor $t$ is divisible by $3$, then $s^2\equiv t^2\equiv 1\mod 3$ and $3|b$. Otherwise $3|a$, in both cases $12|abc$.

Comment: you're a godsend! Thank you so much -- I didn't realize it was that simple!

Comment: actually, for the second half, $s^2$ and $t^2$ being equivalent to 1 mod 3, how does that lead to $3|c$?

Comment: but the numerator of c is $s^2 + t^2$, not $s^2 - t^2$

Comment: Again, you're a godsend! Seriously, thank you so much! Cannot place enough emphasis on my appreciation

Comment: @JohnL. no problem. Glad to hear it was helpful.